# Where can I download WordPress themes from?

Tags: themes

What sites offer WordPress themes to download? (Can be paid-for or free)

It's community wiki so if we had one site per answer, and with a little additional detail on each site, what sort of themes they generally offer, whether their themes are paid-for or free etc.

Comment: Many already know this, but in case someone is new, and looking for WP themes, NEVER download themes from any site other than the official WP repository, or the author/company's official website. You are asking to get your site hacked if you do.

Answer (score 21):

### WordPress Offical Repository

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes

Official repository hosted by WordPress.  Hosts several free themes and offers automatic updates.

Answer (score 8):

### ThemeForest

http://themeforest.net

ThemeForest hosts several premium themes for WordPress, Joomla, and other CMS platforms.  They also sell a few standalone scripts.  Check out the [WordPress-specific category](http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress) for just WP stuff, though.

Answer (score 7):

## Smashing Magazine

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/wordpress/

I like to use Smashing Magazine. While they don't have themes directly. They are constantly doing reviews on themes and even a Top 40 / Top 100 etc. The link above is the tag for Wordpress on their site, so you there will be a few other WP related articles, but a great source for some high quality themes.

Answer (score 6):

### Woo Themes

http://www.woothemes.com/

Premium WordPress theme developers with a *lot* of stellar options.  Just keep in mind that there's no one-off theme purchase option.  A single fee will buy you 3 themes ... or you can subscribe by the month for multiple themes over that.  Details are on [their pricing page](http://www.woothemes.com/pricing/).

Answer (score 6):

### StudioPress

http://www.studiopress.com/

StudioPress offers the premium Genesis framework, along with several child themes.

Answer (score 6):

### Elegant Themes

http://www.elegantthemes.com

Elegant Themes is a really good deal too, subscription-based but you get access to all his themes (and there are a lot of really nice ones)

Answer (score 4):

### Theme Hybrid

http://themehybrid.com/themes

Free child themes for Hybrid parent theme.

Answer (score 3):

### Top WordPress Themes

http://topwpthemes.com

I've used the Top Wordpress Themes site.

Comment: Note: this site appears to be mostly a re-distributor of fabthemes.com.

Answer (score 3):

### Frugal

http://frugaltheme.com

Frugal is a highly flexible Premium Theme. It provides an admin interface with over 600 options for precise control over a site's Design, Performance & SEO. Frugal has a number of License Options ranging from $89-$499

Answer (score 1):

### Press75

http://www.press75.com/

Press75 is mostly premium themes, but there are a few free ones in there too.
Many are optimized for video content.

Answer (score 1):

### RocketTheme

http://www.rockettheme.com/

Another premium theme resource that hosts themes for WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, and phpBB.  The themes are high-quality, feature several customizable features, and sometimes come with multiple pre-set color scheme "skins."  [Membership](https://www.rockettheme.com/join-a-club) is both time-based and **entitlement**-based (meaning you get a set number of theme downloads).

Comment: Be careful, they are using mootools with wordpress -.-'

Comment: There's nothing wrong with MooTools.  It's a valid JS library, just not a popular one because it doesn't play well with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

### Simplethemes

http://www.simplethemes.com

Simplethemes has a couple of free themes, but offers mostly premium themes on a membership basis. Prices range from $39 for membership and includes access to a strong support community.

Answer (score 1):

### Performancing Themes

http://performancing.com/wordpress-themes/

Somewhat oldish, but clean and nice free themes.

Answer (score 1):

### Commercially Supported GPL Themes

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/commercial/

WordPress.org maintains a directory of [Commercially Supported GPL Themes](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/commercial/). Let me quote what they say about those themes...

> While our directory is full of fantastic themes, sometimes people want
>   to use something that they know has support behind it, and don't mind
>   paying for that. Contrary to popular belief, GPL doesn't say that
>   everything must be zero-cost, just that when you receive the software
>   or theme that it not restrict your freedoms in how you use it.
>
> With that in mind, here are a collection of folks who provide GPL
>   themes with extra paid services available around them. Some of them
>   you may pay for access, some of them are membership sites, some may
>   give you the theme for zero-cost and just charge for support. What
>   they all have in common is people behind them who support open source,
>   WordPress, and its GPL license.

Answer (score 0):

### BlogOhBLog!

http://www.blogohblog.com/category/wordpress-themes/

Free themes (as well as premium). Don't know about current but older one were under CC license (for those who care).

Answer (score 0):

## WP-Mojo.com

http://wp-mojo.com

It's a comprehensive collection of the best WordPress (premium and free) themes. You can browse, search and test drive over 800 themes form the most popular WP themes providers.

Answer (score 0):

## ColorVila WordPress Themes

http://colorvila.com/category/themes/

It's a quality and affordable WordPress Theme Club.