# How customizable is a self-hosted WordPress blog compared to a Blogger blog?

Tags: theme-development, css, customization, templates, comparison

I currently have a **Blogspot** blog and I'm thinking of making the leap to a *self-hosted* **WordPress** one instead. Everything I've seems to suggest this is the best way to go for the best possible experience, but main concern is customizability.

I've messed around with a few Blogspot blogs and I know that you're given pretty much full access in terms of changing the look of your blog. I can get in there pretty "deep" and do whatever I like.

When I've read about WordPress, though, a lot of people complain about the lack of customization. Is this true? Are they getting confused with the non-self-hosted version? Just how much visual customization will I get in a *self-hosted* WP blog? I'd really like to know that I have full control over how things look before I take the plunge!

Thanks a for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front-end customization options in self-hosted WordPress are absolute. You can edit whatever you want in PHP/HTML templates and CSS style sheets.

While WordPress comes with single theme ("Twenty Ten" at moment) the availability of third party free and paid themes for it is **huge**.

See:

- [Where can I download WordPress themes from?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29/where-can-i-download-wordpress-themes-from) for good list of sources for ready-made themes;
- [WordPress frameworks and parent themes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/wordpress-frameworks-and-parent-themes) if you are more into developing or deeply customizing one yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> "a lot of people seem to say that you only get access to the CSS once you've paid."

I think you're confusing WordPress.com with self-hosted WordPress. WordPress.com is a blog service similar in concept to Blogger. Self-hosted WordPress is a different beast entirely, and you have full access to the code running your blog.